# Possible to set up email server using Comcast Business?

Tags: smtp, email-server

I'm in no way an expert on this, and realize I might just get told that I'm inexperienced and should not even bother, but I want to know if it's possible to set up an email server on one of our computers while we're using Comcast's Business Internet. We have an email campaign that is generating too many return emails for me to use our Google Apps' SMTP. Would creating our own email server bypass emails-per-hour or -per-day limits imposed by Google Apps, or would we run into Comcasts' limitations too? This isn't spam related, we're not selling anything and we're emailing our users.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an email server on Comcast Business.  However if you're sending out mass mailings you will have very careful on how you go about that or you will get blacklisted and all of your emails will be marked as spam.  And potentially can expose yourself to some legal risks associated with the [CAN-SPAM Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN-SPAM_Act_of_2003) and other anti-spam laws.  Even though you're just email your own users I believe you still have to provide ways for them to opt out of emails.  But there are some exceptions where there is a relationship of some sort involved.  Just make sure you fully understand them.

I think you would be better off using a mass mailing service such as [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp).  Companies like this are trusted and will not only help make sure that your email doesn't end up in junk folders.  But they also will help you manage your mailing list, allow people to unsubscribe, and provide you good analytics to your email campaigns.  Basically they will provide you with an easy way to legally mass email.

Comment: Thanks. We actually use a mass mailing system to send _out_ these emails, and have opt-outs and our address, etc., doing it all legally by the books, but users who submit a form on our site, the results of that form get sent out via Google Apps SMTP and only to our own email accounts (not spamming others), but we've hit that limit. I'd need some kind of mailing solution so we don't hit these limits, and am wondering if there is one outside of creating my own mail server.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to ask your comcast rep. if they block SMTP, but I believe this is allowed. As long as you aren't spamming and it is legitimate mail, all should be fine.